# Pushing a file into a specific folder on a computer from ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, repository

I have a rails app for online orders at a restaurant, I need to push a txt file into a specific folder on the computer running our POS. So basically when a user submits an order the rails app needs to create a txt file and drop that into a directory on the in house computer at said restaurant.

how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Did you try anything? What do you mean "on a computer"? Is it a different "server" than where your Rails is installed? Which protocols are installed? ssh/samba/ftp?

Comment: The rails app is going to be hosted on heroku, the target computer is physically located in the restaurant and it's running windows . As for protocols installed I'm not sure. I haven't tried anything because I'm not sure where to start. Is it possible to set the target folder up as a repository then have my rails app push files into it? Sorry if this seems vague I'm just at a bit of a dead end @EricDuminil

Comment: `File.open(..., 'w')` is a good place to start. What's the problem?

Comment: @ChadTheDev, one option is to write a separate program (can be in Ruby) that will run on Windows on connect to the server regularly to download the files. I'm not sure how large these files will be but the server can expose an endpoint (preferably requiring authentication with a token) that will return the data either as an archive or JSON (`{"file1.txt":"content", ...}`). @ChadTheDev, would this work?

Comment: I'm not asking how to write the file I'm asking the best way to push these files into a directory on a different computer @Tadman

Comment: So basically I create an API that returns the data needed to make these text files then write a separate program that regularly makes calls to this API, then that program can write the file and drop it into the target folder. Also to answer your question these txt files will be small probably 1000 characters at most

Comment: @ChadTheDev What methods are available? Can you `rsync` it? Can you dump it on a shared drive? You've given very little information on the parameters here.

Comment: @tadman Apologies for the ambiguity of the question part of the problem i think is I'm not entirely sure what I'm asking, I'll try to explain. I have a rails app running an online order system for a restaurant. When this app creates an order it needs to drop a text file into a directory named OLO located on a computer in the basement of this restaurant. The target computer is running windows and i can install any software necessary to assist

Comment: Use a shared drive. Figure out how. Then the rest is simply a matter of writing a file.

Comment: @tadman the problem with using a shared drive is in the purpose of these text files. These text files are live orders, once they get dropped into the correct directory on the computer running our POS system the POS will read these these files and make an order. Then once the ticket gets closed out the POS system will delete the order file. What I'm really looking for is a way to sync a directory in my rails app with the OLO directory on the computer running the POS system so that anytime either system adds or removes a file it syncs. Is there a way to set this up?

Comment: You're really over-thinking this here. **Make a file on a shared drive**. If you need a back-up, make two files. Shared drive support is built into Windows, it's not even hard. Everything else will end up being a regrettable hack by comparison.